# This code assigns to the age variable the default value 0

Tags: c#, properties, output

I am trying to create a property Age inside Student class. I have written the code below but when I run it, the value 0 is assigned immediately to the age variable.

I want to allow the user to enter information from the console but I also need to handle possible errors inside Age property.

I have the following code inside Student class:

```
    private int age;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            string age1 = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                int.Parse(age1);
            }

            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Age was not entered.");
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                if (value < 0 || value > 100)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid age!");
                }
                /*else
                {
                    age = value;
                }*/
            }
            age = value;
        }
    }
    public void PrintInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Age: {Age} ");

    }
```

And this inside the Main method:

```
        Console.Write("Please enter age: ");
        Console.WriteLine(student.Age);
        student.PrintInformation();
```

I need to have this output-> Age:(age entered from the user). How can I fix this?

Comment: You're going to want to pull most of that logic out of your property setter.

Comment: In the `set` accessor, at first you do not use the implicit parameter `value` holding the value the property is being set to. Instead you consider a `string age1 = Console.ReadLine();`, and tries to parse it as `int` (without picking up the resulting value, and without using the `TryParse` method meant for this scenario). In the end, you set the backing variable to `value` after all. Can you see the problems?

Comment: Two questions to ask yourself as you try and fix this. a) Why don't you do anything with the return value of `int.Parse`? b) Where did `value` come from?

Comment: This looks like a culmination of university project assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Reading user's input inside a setter method is a terrible idea. You should read the input outside of the setter value, and **before you print it**. The setter should at most contain logic that actually sets the value of your property or calculates something, but it should be written in the simplest way as possible.

That being said, what is going wrong with your code is that you are actually just printing the age of the student in `Console.WriteLine(student.Age);`, which doesn't even call the setter method of your `Age` property, which in turn doesn't ever call `Console.ReadLine()` at all to read the user's input.

You should go for something along the following lines for the `Age` property:

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

And for your input/output operations (probably inside of your program's Main() method):

```
string age1 = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    student.Age = int.Parse(age1);
    if (student.Age < 0 || student.Age > 100)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid age!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Age: {student.Age} ");

}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered.");
}
```

Comment: The code is not correct. It throws an error: The name 'value' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry for that. `value` was supposed to be `student.Age`.

Comment: ArgumentNullException doesn't work and when the age is more than 100 it doesn't display the message but assigns the given value. So that doesn't work too.

Comment: This question is a bit old for me, but I guess I just based on your original post's code to write an answer without actually testing the code. The answer is valid now. If  `age1` contains an empty or invalid number, a `FormatException` will be thrown. The age can only be tested after it is correctly parsed, thus it should happen after the parsing, not in an exception catch block.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its very unusual to want to interact with the console in a property getter/setter.

   - This also falls under the category of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). I.e is it really the students job in life to interact with standard input. What if you change this from a console app to a web app, or a WPF app.. you will have to re-plumb all this logic
2. Don't use `Parse` for user input, use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) it returns true or false if the string can be parsed as an integer

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

For this application, You could probably (and neatly) do your validation in a while loop at the higher level of your console app.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter age between 0 and 100");

int age = 0;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out  age) || age < 0 || age > 100)
   Console.WriteLine("You had one job, enter a correct age between 0 and 100 (inclusively)");

student.Age = age;
```

As a second line of defence, you could do something like this (debatable)

```
public int Age
{
   get => _age;
   set
   {
      if (value < 0 )
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Negative aged people are absurd");

      _age = value;
   }
}
```

**Note** : There are many ways to do this, however the take home points are; Using the proper parse methods; and keeping your getters and setters light as possible. Yeah sure you can validate in them and throw depending on your needs, though interacting with the console within them is very suspect